# Write Text To File

Tags: c++-cli, text-files

When I was trying to write text to a file in C++, nothing ever appeared in the area.
I don't know if it was because I was using my own file extension, but when I do that in C#, it works.

I was using the code:

```
using namespace System::IO;
```

---

```
File::WriteAllText("C:/mypath/myfolder/mydocument.cra");
```

Is there anything I should be doing?

Comment: So where is your C++ code ?

Comment: That's C++/CLI, not C++

Comment: shouldn't WriteAllText take some parameter that's the stuff to write?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ofstream doesn't flush](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113229/ofstream-doesnt-flush)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you can use `fstream`,

```
#include <fstream>

std::fstream fs;
fs.open ("test.txt", std::fstream::out );

fs << " some input";

fs.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) method takes a second parameter, the text to write to the file.

```
File::WriteAllText("C:\\mypath\\myfolder\\mydocument.txt", "Hello from C++/CLI!");
```

This API will replace the entire contents of the file with whatever you specify, so you'll have to build up the entire contents in memory before you write it.